# Error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'f'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
def train_apparentflow_net():

    code_path = config.code_dir
    #f = "0,1,2,3,4,5" 
    f= 0,1,2,3,4,5
    fold = int(sys.argv[1])          
    print('fold = {}'.format(fold))
    if fold == 0:
        mode_train = 'all'
        mode_val = 'all'
    elif fold in range(1,6):
        mode_train = 'train'
        mode_val = 'val'
    else:
        print('Incorrect fold')
```

I executed the code from the command line and passed the argument `f` (which contains the values 0,1,2,3,4,5) into argv arguments in the terminal like this `!python train_apparentflow_net.py f`, but I received an error:

```
 fold = int(sys.argv[1])   
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'f'
```

Comment: "that refuses converting the f to int" <- what int would you like to get from `int('f')`?

Comment: "which contains the values 0,1,2,3,4,5" <- this does not make sense. The string `'f'` contains the character `'f'` and that's what you're passing on the command line.

Comment: Looking at the code, it appears `fold` (the input parameter) should be an integer between 0 and 5 inclusive, not `f`.

Comment: please how exactly in terms of code line for fold to contain these values?

Comment: timgeb yes i want to get int(sys.argv[1]) and the arguments should be 0,1,23,4,5

Answer (score 0):

You are somehow passing a string (which include "f") and then try to convert it to a integer. this is the same as if you would do `int("f")` f is not a number thus it can't be converted to a integer. Hope this helped you <3